# Access a Groovy variable within shell step in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

`SSHUER` in `stage one` prints as required. But in `stage two` it doesn't print and gives me a null value. All three attempt statements in `stage two` are not working. I can't use script block as I have some special characters in the actual code.  Any suggestions as to how to fetch the value of SSHUSER in `stage two`.

```
def SSHUSER

environment {
if(params.CLOUD == 'google') {
   SSHUSER = "test1"
} else if (params.CLOUD == 'azure') {
   SSHUSER = "test2"
}
}

pipeline {
    stage('stage one') {
      steps {
        echo "first attempt '${SSHUSER}'"
      }
    }

    stage('stage two') {
      steps {
      sh '''#!/bin/bash
          echo "first attempt '${SSHUSER}'"
          echo "second attempt \${SSHUSER}"
          echo "thrid attempt \$SSHUSER"

          if ssh  \${SSHUSER}@$i 'test -e /tmp/test'";
          then
              echo "$i file exists "
          fi
         '''
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your usage of the `environment` block is a bit weird, it should reside inside the `pipeline` block and variables should be initialized inside the `environment` block.
If it is defined outside the variables will not be passed to the shell script as environment variables.

If you want to use the `environment` block inside the `pipeline' block just define the parameters (as strings) you want and they will be available for all stages, and they will be passed as environment variables for the shell.
For example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters{
        string(name: 'CLOUD', defaultValue: 'google', description: '')
    }
    environment {
        SSHUSER = "${params.CLOUD == 'google' ? 'test1' : 'test2'}"
    }
    stages {
        stage('stage one') {
            steps {
                echo "first attempt '${SSHUSER}'"
            }
        }

        stage('stage two') {
            steps {
                sh '''#!/bin/bash
          echo "first attempt '${SSHUSER}'"
          echo "second attempt \${SSHUSER}"
          echo "thrid attempt \$SSHUSER"

          if ssh  \${SSHUSER}@$i 'test -e /tmp/test'";
          then
              echo "$i file exists "
          fi
         '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use the `environment` block or mange the parameters by yourself you can do it outside the `pipeline` block using Global variables but then they will not be passed environment variables and you will need to use string interpolation (`"""` instead of `'''`) to calculate the values when passing the command to the shell:

```
SSHUSER = ''

if(params.CLOUD == 'google') {
    SSHUSER = "test1"
} else if (params.CLOUD == 'azure') {
    SSHUSER = "test2"
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters{
        string(name: 'CLOUD', defaultValue: 'google', description: 'Bitbucket Payload', trim: true)
    }
    stages {
        stage('stage one') {
            steps {
                echo "first attempt '${SSHUSER}'"
            }
        }

        stage('stage two') {
            steps {
                sh """#!/bin/bash
          echo "first attempt '${SSHUSER}'"
          echo "second attempt ${SSHUSER}"
          echo "thrid attempt $SSHUSER"

          if ssh  ${SSHUSER}@\$i 'test -e /tmp/test'";
          then
              echo "\$i file exists "
          fi
         """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to achieve what i need from your example

Comment: @noam if we have assigned a new value to SSHUSER in sh then that value is accessible outside sh block?

Comment: The `SSHUSER` variable will always be accessible for everywhere, however if it was defined in the `environment` directive then its value cannot be changed later on (first example), if it was defined as global parameter (second example) and can be modified inside any step.